# How to find the difference in terms of days from YYYY_MM_DD formatted dates in bigsql?

Tags: bigsql

I want to find the difference between two dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. For example, I have 2 dates `2018-10-31` and `2018-11-07`. I want to find the difference in number of days between those two dates (7 days) in BigSql. I have gone through stack overflow and other websites but couldn't find anything that works as there are very few resources for BigSql.

I have tried below query which works fine for sql server but not for bigsql :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-10-31', '2018-11-07')
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after continuous efforts I found something that worked for me posting here if in case someone looking for the the same:

```
SELECT DAYS_BETWEEN ('2018-10-31', '2018-11-07),
```